# Retry loop until condition met

Tags: loops, sikuli

I am trying to navigate my mouse on object but I want to create a condition that will check if "surowiec" is still on the screen, if not I want to skip loop and go to another one. After it finish the second one get back to first and repeat.

[error] script [ Documents ] stopped with error in line 12 [error] FindFailed ( can not find surowiec.png in R[0,0 1920x1080]@S(0) )

```
w_lewo = Location(345,400)
w_prawo = Location(1570,400)
w_gore = Location(345,400)
w_dol = Location(345,400)

surowiec = "surowiec.png"

while surowiec:
    if surowiec == surowiec:
        exists("surowiec.png") 
        if exists != None:
            click("surowiec.png")    
            wait(3)
            exists("surowiec.png") 
        elif exists == None:
            surowiec = None    
            click(w_prawo)
            wait(8)
            surowiec = surowiec
```

Comment: This could be Python code...

Comment: Iam trying here to navigate my mouse on object but I want to create a condition that will check if "surowiec" is still on the screen, if not I want it to skip loop and go to another one. After it finish the secound one get back to first and repeat.

Comment: [error] script [ Documents ] stopped with error in line 12
[error] FindFailed ( can not find surowiec.png in R[0,0 1920x1080]@S(0) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a small example:

```
while True:
    if exists(surowiec):
        print('A')
        click(surowiec)
    else: 
        print('B')
    break
```

A while loop that is `True` will always run, until it it meets a `break` to exit the loop. Also have a look at the functions that are available in Sikuli, it can somethimes be hard to find them, that they are available. So here are a few nice ones:

Link: [Link 1](http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html) and [Pushing keys](http://doc.sikuli.org/keys.html) and [Regions](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html)

The commands that I found myself very usefull are `is exists` and `if not exists`, and `find` that will allow to locate an image on the screen. Then you don't have to find an image over and over again if it stays on the same location. `image1 = find(surowiec)`